# Linebreak is not being interpreted as a linebreak in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

On node.js I have a file that goes like this:

```
data().then(v => {
    socket.country = d.country;
    onlineusers += d.name+'<br>';
```

I intend `<br>` to break the line but its being parsed as plain text. How can I have html in my strings?

Comment: Strings are just that - *strings*. They aren’t interpreted for any HTML when they’re set; it depends solely on how you *use* this value downstream. Where is your data being *parsed*, exactly? See also: [ask]

Comment: like this: `io.emit('login', {
     onlineusers: onlineusers
    });`

Comment: Ok, that’s not where it’s being parsed as HTML though. Where is the content of that string being parsed? Assuming it’s received on the other end of a socket, how is the content being parsed and “painted” into the user interface there? What is the relevant code for that? (Please include code in the body of your question, as it’s much more readable and visible there for future visitors to this question)

Comment: HTML should only be used when it is really HTML. You should better design your data model to represent your data, convert the data to HTML only when it is about to be displayed in the page. To me it looks like you should make `onlineusers` an array of string. Then use `onlineusers.push(d.name)` to add an item. When you ready to display the data, use `onlineusers.join("<br>")` to generate the HTML to be inserted.

Comment: the client side looks like this: `socket.on('login', (data) => {
    userlist.textContent = data.onlineusers;`

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the way to insert a newline in Javascript

```
data().then(v => {
  socket.country = d.country;
  onlineusers += d.name+'\n';
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering but my question was about html in general, hence the original title. br was intended as a quick example.